# Page not showing special characters

Tags: php, html, character-encoding, fullcalendar

I can't display characters like: `È,~ ã,` Instead of `ç`  I'm gettint `Ã§`

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calendario</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src='calendario/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='calendario/fullcalendar.js'></script>
    <script src='calendario/lang/pt-br.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='calendario/fullcalendar.css' charset='UTF-8'/>
    <style type="text/css">     
        .teste{height: 100%; width: 700px;}

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //Page is now ready, initialize calenda.

        $('#calendario').fullCalendar({    
            firstDay: 1,
            weekends: false,            

        })
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="teste">
        <div id="calendario"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can't find the source of the problem. I'm using `Sublimetext2` and already checked the file by console command `view.encoding()` and already tried `File > Save with Encoding > UTF-8`. I don't know what else to try.

I read that `Fullcalendar`does not write a HTML content but a value().So I tried this without success.

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {                                          
    element.find('div.fc-title').html(element.find('div.fc-title').text());                   
}
```

Tried to see the localhost page on Mozila and it's fine. Aparenttly, the problem is with Chrome D:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those types of characters are marked as *reserved* in the `Html` langage. Which means, you have to replace them with *character entities*.

You can learn more about *Diacritical Marks* [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

I hope I've been of any help.